# Using pandas to scrape weather data from wundergound

Tags: python, pandas, import, weather-api

I came across a very useful set of scripts on the Shane Lynn for the
[Analysis of Weather data](http://www.shanelynn.ie/analysis-of-weather-data-using-pandas-python-and-seaborn/). The first script, used to scrape data from Weather Underground, is as follows:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from dateutil import parser, rrule
from datetime import datetime, time, date
import time

def getRainfallData(station, day, month, year):
    """
    Function to return a data frame of minute-level weather data for a single Wunderground PWS station.

    Args:
        station (string): Station code from the Wunderground website
        day (int): Day of month for which data is requested
        month (int): Month for which data is requested
        year (int): Year for which data is requested

    Returns:
        Pandas Dataframe with weather data for specified station and date.
    """
    url = "http://www.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXDailyHistory.asp?ID={station}&day={day}&month={month}&year={year}&graphspan=day&format=1"
    full_url = url.format(station=station, day=day, month=month, year=year)
    # Request data from wunderground data
    response = requests.get(full_url, headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'})
    data = response.text
    # remove the excess <br> from the text data
    data = data.replace('<br>', '')
    # Convert to pandas dataframe (fails if issues with weather station)
    try:
        dataframe = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), index_col=False)
        dataframe['station'] = station
    except Exception as e:
        print("Issue with date: {}-{}-{} for station {}".format(day,month,year, station))
        return None
    return dataframe

# Generate a list of all of the dates we want data for
start_date = "2016-08-01"
end_date = "2016-08-31"
start = parser.parse(start_date)
end = parser.parse(end_date)
dates = list(rrule.rrule(rrule.DAILY, dtstart=start, until=end))

# Create a list of stations here to download data for
stations = ["ILONDON28"]
# Set a backoff time in seconds if a request fails
backoff_time = 10
data = {}

# Gather data for each station in turn and save to CSV.
for station in stations:
    print("Working on {}".format(station))
    data[station] = []
    for date in dates:
        # Print period status update messages
        if date.day % 10 == 0:
            print("Working on date: {} for station {}".format(date, station))
        done = False
        while done == False:
            try:
                weather_data = getRainfallData(station, date.day, date.month, date.year)
                done = True
            except ConnectionError as e:
                # May get rate limited by Wunderground.com, backoff if so.
                print("Got connection error on {}".format(date))
                print("Will retry in {} seconds".format(backoff_time))
                time.sleep(10)
        # Add each processed date to the overall data
        data[station].append(weather_data)
    # Finally combine all of the individual days and output to CSV for analysis.
    pd.concat(data[station]).to_csv("data/{}_weather.csv".format(station))
```

However, I get the error:

```
Working on ILONDONL28
Issue with date: 1-8-2016 for station ILONDONL28
Issue with date: 2-8-2016 for station ILONDONL28
Issue with date: 3-8-2016 for station ILONDONL28
Issue with date: 4-8-2016 for station ILONDONL28
Issue with date: 5-8-2016 for station ILONDONL28
Issue with date: 6-8-2016 for station ILONDONL28
```

Can anyone help me with this error?

The data for the chosen station and the time period is available, as shown at this [link](https://www.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXDailyHistory.asp?ID=ILONDONL28&day=01&month=08&year=2016&graphspan=day&format=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output you are getting is because an exception is being raised. If you added a `print e` you would see that this is because `import io` was missing from the top of the script. Secondly, the station name you gave was out by one character. Try the following:

```
import io
import requests
import pandas as pd
from dateutil import parser, rrule
from datetime import datetime, time, date
import time

def getRainfallData(station, day, month, year):
    """
    Function to return a data frame of minute-level weather data for a single Wunderground PWS station.

    Args:
        station (string): Station code from the Wunderground website
        day (int): Day of month for which data is requested
        month (int): Month for which data is requested
        year (int): Year for which data is requested

    Returns:
        Pandas Dataframe with weather data for specified station and date.
    """

    url = "http://www.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXDailyHistory.asp?ID={station}&day={day}&month={month}&year={year}&graphspan=day&format=1"
    full_url = url.format(station=station, day=day, month=month, year=year)

    # Request data from wunderground data
    response = requests.get(full_url)
    data = response.text
    # remove the excess <br> from the text data
    data = data.replace('<br>', '')

    # Convert to pandas dataframe (fails if issues with weather station)
    try:
        dataframe = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), index_col=False)
        dataframe['station'] = station
    except Exception as e:
        print("Issue with date: {}-{}-{} for station {}".format(day,month,year, station))
        return None

    return dataframe

# Generate a list of all of the dates we want data for
start_date = "2016-08-01"
end_date = "2016-08-31"
start = parser.parse(start_date)
end = parser.parse(end_date)
dates = list(rrule.rrule(rrule.DAILY, dtstart=start, until=end))

# Create a list of stations here to download data for
stations = ["ILONDONL28"]
# Set a backoff time in seconds if a request fails
backoff_time = 10
data = {}

# Gather data for each station in turn and save to CSV.
for station in stations:
    print("Working on {}".format(station))
    data[station] = []
    for date in dates:
        # Print period status update messages
        if date.day % 10 == 0:
            print("Working on date: {} for station {}".format(date, station))
        done = False
        while done == False:
            try:
                weather_data = getRainfallData(station, date.day, date.month, date.year)
                done = True
            except ConnectionError as e:
                # May get rate limited by Wunderground.com, backoff if so.
                print("Got connection error on {}".format(date))
                print("Will retry in {} seconds".format(backoff_time))
                time.sleep(10)
        # Add each processed date to the overall data
        data[station].append(weather_data)
    # Finally combine all of the individual days and output to CSV for analysis.
    pd.concat(data[station]).to_csv(r"data/{}_weather.csv".format(station))
```

Giving you an output CSV file starting as follows:

```
,Time,TemperatureC,DewpointC,PressurehPa,WindDirection,WindDirectionDegrees,WindSpeedKMH,WindSpeedGustKMH,Humidity,HourlyPrecipMM,Conditions,Clouds,dailyrainMM,SoftwareType,DateUTC,station
0,2016-08-01 00:05:00,17.8,11.6,1017.5,ESE,120,0.0,0.0,67,0.0,,,0.0,WeatherCatV2.31B93,2016-07-31 23:05:00,ILONDONL28
1,2016-08-01 00:20:00,17.7,11.0,1017.5,SE,141,0.0,0.0,65,0.0,,,0.0,WeatherCatV2.31B93,2016-07-31 23:20:00,ILONDONL28
2,2016-08-01 00:35:00,17.5,10.8,1017.5,South,174,0.0,0.0,65,0.0,,,0.0,WeatherCatV2.31B93,2016-07-31 23:35:00,ILONDONL28
```

If you are not getting a CSV file, I suggest you add a full path to the output filename.

Comment: Martin,
thank you so much.
The station name was correct in my script (but wrong in the code I copied).
Adding `import io` is what actually solved it.

Comment: is it possible that the html adress from wonderground has been changed? I get an error like "Error 404: Page Not Found"

Comment: If you copy/pasted the script correctly, there should not be a `Page Not Found` error, but it does appear that the website has changed and so the data is no longer returned. It will probably require a different URL format.